# Mixing FirebaseUI Auth with "raw" Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

FirebaseUI has the option of authenticating a user silently via `AuthUI.getInstance().silentSignIn()`. My issue is that I need to sign in specific users silently, and with FirebaseUI it doesn't always work as expected. There seems to be some kind of a caching mechanism which decides which user will get signed in, and I as a developer don't have that much control over it as I'd like. Specially when signing in Email/Password accounts.

Firebase Auth on the other hand has those very clear methods like `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(strEmail, strPassword)` or `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null))` (after using `.startActivityForResult(Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(m_gacGoogleApiClient), RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)`)

Is it possible to safely use those Firebase Auth methods directly instead of `AuthUI.getInstance().silentSignIn()`, or or will this cause problem because the underlying system of `AuthUI` may then not be in sync with the state of Firebase/FirebaseUI?

Because if that is not possible, I will be forced to ditch FirebaseUI entirely. I like the initial sign-up procedure of FirebaseUI a lot, it makes many things easier, but the silent sign-in is very important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FirebaseUI Authentication components don't keep their own state. So mixing AuthUI methods with regular Firebase Authentication methods should not create problems with mixed state.

If you experience any problems, please report in an issue here, on on the Github repo of FirebaseUI for your platform.